# Servlet exception with Lucene demo class

Tags: java, servlets, lucene

I am just trying to invoke the basic Lucene demo class from a servlet and am getting this exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet SearcServlet threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.store.Directory
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
>     at servlet.SearcServlet.doPost(SearcServlet.java:50)

My servlet method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    try {
        String[] arguments = new String[] {"123"};
        SearchFiles.main(arguments);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The search is getting executed when i call it  from another Java class, but when I do it from a servlet I get this exception. I am using the lucene demo search class, no other functionality included.

Comment: The arguments are not required for basic search as we enter the input from console.

Comment: Did you include all the required Lucene JAR's in your WAR?

Comment: Yes i have added them to the project,Its a dynamic web project,I have not built the war file yet. The java class by itself is working,but when called from servlet, crashes

Comment: And ***all*** these Lucene JARs, have been placed into the WEB-INF/lib folder, underneath of your `WebContent` folder?

Comment: No,I added them to the java buld path as external jar files.

Comment: Add them to you WebContent directoy, in the WEB-INF/lib folder, and then retry your test.

Comment: yES,iT WORKS NOW>tHANK U.Y doesn it get added dynamically?

Comment: It's an Eclipse thing, it allows you to maintain a separate, development configuration of your project (for testing etc). Not very useful for Dynamic Web Projects though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is related to Java Classpath. `ClassNotFoundException` comes when JVM tries to load a class at runtime dynamically and if that class is not found in classpath it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

As, you are using third party API called Apache Lucene, you need to place all required *jar* files to application classpath.

For a web application default classpath is `/WEB-INF/lib` directory under **webapp** or **WebContent**  directory.

Copy all required *jar* files there, eclipse takes care everything rest.